# How to set Jupyter Notebook iopub_data_rate_limit from Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I use several different machines regularly, so I typically have some notebook setting that I include with my import statements to avoid having to change configuration files all the time:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))  
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Now, I have encountered the "IOPub data rate exceeded", so I would typically change c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit in the config file.

My question is if there is simple way to do this from within a notebook instead?